# How to look for value with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to grab person name(Alex Key here) from markup like this:

```
<div class="link_container">
<a class="follow_card" data-uuid="e47443373cfa93d5341ab809f0700b82" 
data-type="person" data-name="Alex Key" data-permalink="/person/alex-acree-2" 
data-image="" data-follower-count="0" href="/person/alex-key-2">Alex Key</a></div>
```

I try code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from django.http import HttpResponse
import os

def impTxt(request):
abs_path = os.path.dirname(__file__) # i.e. /path/to/dir/
root_dir = os.path.split(abs_path)[0] #i.e. /path/to/root_of_project/
imp_file_path = "files/links.txt"
abs_imp_file_path = os.path.join(root_dir, imp_file_path) # abs_path to file


with open(abs_imp_file_path, 'r') as inputfile:
    imp_txt = []
    # print imp_txt
    for line in inputfile:
        imp_txt.append(str(line).strip('[]'))
        print line
        # print imp_txt
    for link in imp_txt:
        # print link
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Volumes/Storage/downloads_storage/chromedriver')
        driver.get(link)
        driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
        driver.set_window_size(100000, 200000)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(1) 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
        text = soup.find('a',{'class': 'follow_card'}).getText()
        print text
        # content = {
        # 'text':text,
        # }
        return render(request, "web/parser.html",{})
```

but get None. Please point out a way to find variables inside a tag.

> UPDATED: added full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work with your markup:

```
text = dict(soup.find('a').attrs)['data-name']
```

But you might need to check first if `data-name` is present in the dictionary, because otherwise it will trow an error.

Comment: "KeyError at /web/parser/
'data-name'"

Comment: @AndriyKravchenko, can you share with us the value of `driver.page_source` ?

Comment: The page I try to parse is :https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/apple/people and seems it protects from parsing. Here is my console output if I print soup :https://gist.github.com/avkpol/1c298a04e4628ec162d72fc3397ee0ef

Comment: I've tried to parse it in 3 browsers, especially in Safari where I have no third-part plugins and javascript is for sure enabled and everywhere i got the same.And, you are right, if proper key is exist in markup your code works.

Comment: Your problem is that CrunchBase detects bots and shows different content for them. The html that you got not contains the list of people.

Comment: Yes, sure, I have understood it already. But what to do in cases like this?Are the ways to parse such pages?

Comment: Get the html manually using chromes's inspect element, save it to a local file on the server and parse it from there. But I'm not sure if all this is allowed by copyright law or not.. :) Another solution might be to set the user agent for `webdriver` to something that mimic a real user.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to dig in your second way...)

Answer (score 2):

getText() method can do for you:

```
text = soup.find('a',{'class':'follow_card'}).getText()
```

And the class name here is `follow_card`

Comment: Thanks, but ''NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'' occures

Answer (score 1):

Specify the class name in `soup.find()`,

```
>>>soup.find('a',{'class': 'follow_card'}).getText()
u'Alex Key'
```

Comment: Just the same: ''NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'' . Nothing can understand!

Comment: @AndriyKravchenko check for the class name. I've used your Html data to get the text.